# Is it permissible to work for a client who wants erotic stories?

Tags: sharia, fatwa

Is it permissible for a novelist/writer to work for a client who wants erotic stories?

Please cite references from Quran/Hadith, if there are any.

And also, are there any fatwas from shia scholars regarding this ruling?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

[Quran 5/2](http://quran.com/5/2):

> but do not help one another in sin and transgression [al-Maa’idah 5:2]

Fatwa about erotic stories [here](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/34489).

Comment: This is half of the answer. You need to also show making erotic stories are haraam.

Comment: The answer should be complete now.